# v2.81 Rock generator

Tags: add-on

Where would the Rock Generator be in the official 2.81 release?

It used to be in the Testing category in v2.81 alpha/beta *(blender-2.81-c25a910e4ec0-windows64 anyway)*

There's nothing in the testing category now.

So where have all those items gone? it's not all moved, just gone.

The only difference is this is the installation rather than standalone zip archive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer below is obsolete since the *Rock Generator* is now part of *Extra Objects* add-on since commit [rBA7347930a0fa14e752929e28c9b48adf74597b018](https://developer.blender.org/rBA7347930a0fa14e752929e28c9b48adf74597b018). The separate *Rock Generator* add-on has been removed from the add-ons contrib repository by commit [rBAC70b649775eeeebedb02c1c7b7aa996a7f6294177](https://developer.blender.org/rBAC70b649775eeeebedb02c1c7b7aa996a7f6294177).

---

The release versions only contain the official add-ons. Anything that is from the [*Blender Add-ons Contrib*](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC/) repository isn't included.

You can either clone the repository if you're familiar with git or you can download a .tar.gz archive of the latest commit of the contribution add-ons using the following [link](http://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender-addons-contrib.git/snapshot/HEAD.tar.gz). Extract and copy the files into `./2.81/scripts/addons_contrib/` and you should be able to activate them.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was only a missing folder thing. extracting to 
 scripts/addons_contrib and refreshing adds them all back.

Comment: Great! If that solved your problem, please consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to it.