# 2.81.16 No Rock Generator

Tags: add-on

I want to install the rock generator for v2.81.16 and I found this answer, [v2.81 Rock generator](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159164/v2-81-rock-generator)

I have downloaded the zip and installed it as described but I still do not have the rock generator. I have lots of other addons so I think I placed the contents in the correct directory. Has something changed since this linked question was answered?
[image: No rock]

[image: lots of other addons]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linked answer is obsolete since the *Rock Generator* is now part of *Extra Objects* add-on since commit [rBA7347930a0fa14e752929e28c9b48adf74597b018](https://developer.blender.org/rBA7347930a0fa14e752929e28c9b48adf74597b018). The separate *Rock Generator* add-on has been removed from the add-ons contrib repository by commit [rBAC70b649775eeeebedb02c1c7b7aa996a7f6294177](https://developer.blender.org/rBAC70b649775eeeebedb02c1c7b7aa996a7f6294177).

If you are using a 2.82 alpha build from the 12th of December or later, enable the *Extra Objects* add-on. The *Rock Generator* operator will appear in the *Add > Mesh* menu.

[image: Extra Objects add-on]

[image: Rock generator in menu]

If you are using a build of 2.82 which doesn't include the commit, because it was compiled before the 12th of December, you will need to [download a more recent version](https://builder.blender.org/download/).

If you don't want to use the latest 2.82 alpha which includes this change, you will have to clone the repository and either manually replace your older *Extra Objects* add-on with the updated version or revert to a commit where the *Rock Generator* was still a separate add-on. Both options require experience with git.

Comment: I'm running 2.82a now and I don't see it anywhere,. I am searching for rock

Comment: Is your version of the alpha from the 12th of December or later? Have you enabled the *Extra Objects* add-on?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are looking in the wrong area. It is in community.

Comment: I am using 2.82. I actually did not find it in 2.81 either. However, I cannot get it to install properly in 2.82 even though it is there in the community section. It probably only works in 2.80 right now.

Comment: I'm running 2.82a now and I don't see it anywhere,.  I am searching for rock

Comment: I only have "geodesic domes" which is useful, but not a rock generator as far as I know, 2.81. 2.8 had it for me but not 2.81.